# sip.conf configuration file - add new line to each record

Tags: php, python, ruby, regex, linux

I have a sip configuration file which looks like this:

```
[1664]
username=1664
mailbox=1664@8360
host=192.168.254.3
type=friend
subscribemwi=no
[1679]
username=1679
mailbox=1679@8360
host=192.168.254.3
type=friend
subscribemwi=no
[1700]
username=1700
mailbox=1700@8360
host=192.168.254.3
type=friend
subscribemwi=no
[1701]
username=1701
mailbox=1701@8360
host=192.168.254.3
type=friend
subscribemwi=no
```

For each record I need to add another line (**vmxten** for each record) for example the above becomes:

```
[1664]
username=1664
mailbox=1664@8360
host=192.168.254.3
type=friend
subscribemwi=no
vmexten=1664
[1679]
username=1679
mailbox=1679@8360
host=192.168.254.3
type=friend
subscribemwi=no
vmexten=1679
[1700]
username=1700
mailbox=1700@8360
host=192.168.254.3
type=friend
subscribemwi=no
vmexten=1700
[1701]
username=1701
mailbox=1701@8360
host=192.168.254.3
type=friend
subscribemwi=no
vmexten=1701
```

What would you say would be the quickest way to do this? there are hundreds of records in the file, therefore modifying all of the records by hand would take a long time.

Would you use Regex? Would you use sed? I'm interested to know how you would approach the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match with `^\[(\d+)\]` and replace by `[\1]\r\nvmexten=\1`. Unsure if python/ruby use `\1` or `$1`. But I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: Note that this produces a slightly different output to the one the OP asked for, with `vmexten` at the top of the section rather than the bottom. This shouldn't matter though.

Comment: @Eric: correct, but this was the absolute best way of doing it and I really don't think it will matter much.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `(\[(\d+)][^\[]+)` with `\1vmexten=\2\n` works in my text editor